# Prove: If f is a bijective meromorphic function from the Riemann sphere to itself, then f is a Mobius transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Knowing that a meromorphic function f requires f to be either analytic or has a pole at every point in its domain, what does bijective meromorphic mean?

Comment: It means that every $z$ is mapped to a distinct $f(z)$ in the Riemann sphere, and every $w$ in the Riemann sphere has a point that maps to it. (Or equivalently, there is a well-defined global inverse function $z=f^{-1}(w)$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118074/why-is-every-holomorphic-bijection-of-the-riemann-sphere-a-m%C3%B6bius-transformation