# How to show that every conformal map on extended $\Bbb{C}$ is Mobius

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have no problem in showing that a Mobius transformation is a conformal map. I can't find anyway a reference or a simple proof that every conformal map of extended $\Bbb{C}$ can be written as a Mobius transformation.

Can you provide some references ora at least a sketch of the proof?

Comment: Using a Mobius transform, insure $f(\infty)=\infty$, then it follows f entire with a limit at $\infty$, it follows f polynomial, it follows f linear by injectivity, go back to original $f$ Mobius now because step 1

Comment: A more detailed outline can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118076/269764