# Relation between linearity and injectivity of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f$ entire function on $\mathbb C$ and $f$ one-one. Is it true that $f$ is linear?

At least among polynomials the only such functions are linear!

Comment: Why the hypothesis linear?

Comment: this might help you Aneesh http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163780/transcendental-entire-function-aut-mathbbc

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29758/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The link given by @Patience leads to a proof, but one can avoid the heavier things like Picard, Casorati-Weierstrass and the very notion of essential singularity. Liouville's theorem is enough.

Pick a point $a$ such that $f\,'(a)\ne 0$. (I don't even want to argue that $f\,'$ never vanishes). Normalize so that $a=0$, $f(0)=0$, and $f\,'(0)=1$. Since $f$ is an open map, there exists $r>0$ such that $\{w:|w|<r\}\subset f(\{z:|z|<1\})$. The function $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-z}{zf(z)}$$ has a removable singularity at $0$. When $|z|\ge1$, we have $$|g(z)| = \left|\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{f(z)}\right|\le \frac{1}{|z|}+\frac{1}{|f(z)|}\le 1+\frac{1}{r}.$$ Thus, $g$ is a bounded entire function. By Liouville's theorem $g$ is constant, and it follows that $f$ is linear.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Of the answers to this question on other threads which I have seen, this is most similar to [this answer of Zarrax](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29822/).

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks. After writing this, I noticed that $f$ could be assumed to be merely meromorphic, since the poles of $f$ are removable for $g$. Then the conclusion is $f(z)=z/(1-cz)$, where $c$ is not necessarily zero anymore.

Comment: Great answer indeed, +1! I didn't know how to prove this without Casorati-Weierstrass...

Comment: Thank you very much Kovalev!

Comment: @Leonid could you tell me how to normalize and how we can assume $f'(0)=1$?

Comment: @Patience You have a function such that $f\,'(a)\ne 0$. Let $\tilde f(z)=(f(z+a)-f(a))/f\,'(a)$. This new function has $\tilde f(0)=0$, and $\tilde f\,'(0)=1$, as desired. Note that $f$ is linear if and only if $\tilde f$ is linear. So, we can simply work with $\tilde f$ from now on, and even rename it as $f$ to simplify writing.

Comment: $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+cz}$ is linear?

Comment: or as $f$ is non-constant and has no poles so $c=0$ must? and $f(z)=z$?

Comment: also why $g$ has just removable  singularity at $z=0$? I can see $f(0)=0$ so $g$ has a pole at $0$?

Comment: and the conclusion you made assuming $f$ is open map is true?

Comment: $g(z)$ has an infinity plus infinity form so we don't know what it is unless we compute!!
$zg(z)$ has the limit 0 as $z$ tends to 0, so the singularity at $0$ is a removable singularity and g extends to an entire function at 0! So don't bother about what $g(0)$ is!

The open mapping theorem shows the existence of an $r$ such that
$|f(z)|<r$ implies $|z|<1$
Equivalently
$|z|\ge1$ implies $|f(z)|\ge r$ or equivalently
$|z|\ge1$ implies $\frac1{|f(z)|}\le\frac1r$

At the end of it all, indeed $f(z)=z$ because the absence of poles implies $c=0$

So you are done!!

Comment: I am still not convinced about the statement concluded from OMT