# Non-Trivial Self-Inverse Analytic Function In The Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $f$ be a complex-valued function which is analytic for all values of $z$ in the complex plane and which satisfies 
$$f(f(z))= z $$ i.e. it is a self-inverse function. The trivial solutions for $f$ are clearly $f(z)=z$ and $f(z)=-z$. Are there any others?

Edit: There are more "trivial" examples: $f(z)=a-z$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: This is a well studied problem on the Riemann sphere - namely the complex plane plus infinity.  In that context, the only holomorphic, self-inverse functions are the [Mobius functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), $z\rightarrow (az+b)/(cz+d)$. In the everywhere analytic case, $c\neq 0$ and you're left with your two examples.

Comment: Is there a relatively easy proof of that I could understand?

Comment: user31373's answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168629/relation-between-linearity-and-injectivity-of-an-entire-function) gives a proof based on Liouville's theorem that an injective, entire function is linear; the rest is easy. :)

Comment: Is there a more elemental proof?