# if f is an analytical injective on a disc beside 0 then f has a pole or removeable point

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

if f is an analytical  injective on a disc beside 0 then f has a pole or removeable point on z=0.

My try: there can't be an essential singularity, as otherwise, near the pole we would have all the values on the entire plane (but 1).
Now it must be removeable or a simple pole, otherwise we can take the Laurent series, of this function, and there will be at least one value for which we get 2 different roots.

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53303/42969.

Comment: @MartinR nope, I can see why this is not essential singularity, but why can't be 2nd order pole for example?

Comment: That is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566422/42969. (But actually your question does not ask that explicitly.)

Comment: Your question is unclear, it is mostly trivial to show that if $f$ is meromorphic then it must have either a simple pole or $f'$ must have a simple zero at $0$, the hard part is dealing with the essential singularity case that Martin answered to.