# Biholomorphic map $f: \Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C$ with $f(z_1) = z_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $z_1, z_2 \in \Bbb C$. I want to find a biholomorphic map $f: \Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C$ such that $f(z_1) = z_2$, but I do not know how such a map could look like.

Comment: Why not $f(z)=z_2+(z-z_1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A biholomorphic map from $\Bbb C$ onto itself is necessarily *linear*
(see e.g. [entire 1-1 function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29758/entire-1-1-function)), which means that all solutions are given by
$$
 f(z) = z_2 + a(z - z_1)
$$
for some $a \in \Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$.