# Is this function C → C injective?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

Consider f $\colon$ $\mathbb C $ $\to$ $\mathbb C$  given by f (z) = $z^3$

I know that this function is a surjection, but is it injective, thus bijective?

Comment: No, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29758/entire-one-to-one-functions-are-linear): Entire one-to-one functions are linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for example $f(1) = f(e^{2\pi i/3}) = f(e^{4\pi i/3}) = 1$.

[In fact, if you solve $f(z) = w$, you will get exactly three solutions for every $w\neq 0$.]